# Virtuemart Interswitch Payment Gateway

Tags: joomla-extensions

I am trying to create a website using the Joomla and virtuemart.
But I would like to integrate INTERSWITCH Payment gateway into the virtuemart.

There is no in-built option for that. Can some one help find some links which can help to the extend the functionality of Virtuemart Payment System?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the Interswitch Webpay  Gateway, there is a commercial payment plugin you can get here - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/virtuemart-payment-systems/15132. It's about $30 so well worth the $$ unless you are familiar with coding a Virtuemart payment plugin.